# How to write a regular expression that allows non-repeating underscores

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I'm working on a homework assignment to use Flex to create a lexer.  The last requirement I have to meet is:

> The definition for the identifiers should be modified so that underscores can be included, however, consecutive underscores, leading and trailing underscores should not be permitted.

The given regex is `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*`.  Getting it to recognize underscores was easy, I just added it to the second grouping like `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*`.  As is, the regex does not match any strings with leading underscores.

While doing my due diligence to make sure I wasn't posting something I didn't need to, I created this regex that seems to work `[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9][_]?[A-Za-z0-9])*`.  This looks for a letter at the start, then a repeating pattern or alphanumeric character, possible underscore, and alphanumeric character.  While this works, I don't think it is what is expected and was hoping to get some advice on any better ways

I've been testing using the following strings (provided by the instructor):

```
name_1
name__2
_name3
name4_
```

Comment: Try these additional test cases: `n_ame`, `name`, `ab`.

Comment: @sln I doubt your performance analysis applies to `flex`.

Comment: @sln I have a basic understanding of the algorithm used by flex and don't see why it would be faster for the complicated regex than the simple one. I also have a strong suspicion that whichever tool you were using for your benchmarks doesn't use the same algorithm. So that's why I believed that your numbers wouldn't apply to flex. Just so you don't have to take my word for it, I've also done [my own benchmarks](https://gist.github.com/sepp2k/b7cf72da385756caaaadc0a0bd95b9a0) (actually using flex) and found both versions to perform equally.

Comment: @sln Please find a more constructive way of disagreeing with other users. Instead of attacking them personally and calling them ignorant, just dispute their claims with counter-evidence. Focus on the technical aspects, not the people. I deleted your previous comment, because it was [unnecessarily rude](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9][_]?[A-Za-z0-9])*` the first `[A-Za-z0-9]` can/must be omitted (consider e.g. single letter identifiers), leading to `[A-Za-z]([_]?[A-Za-z0-9])*`. That seems to be exactly what was asked, and seems a good exercise to study the effects of combining optional elements under repetition in the regular expression.

Comment: Thank you.  This looks so much better than the one I had even though they have similar results.  I had gotten stuck with `[A-Za-z][_?A-Za-z0-9])*` which I really wanted to work but of course it didn't.  My mistake was grouping them incorrectly.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: What is your reason for using a grouping for the underscore?

Answer (score 1):

To extend your regex to optionally allow only one underscore at a time that too sandwiched within the string, you can use this regex.

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*
```

I've just added `(_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*` part which will allow single underscore followed by at least one alphanumeric character whole of it zero or more times to only keep the underscore optional.

Now you will have to take care of other aspects as I am not familiar with flex.

Comment: Why would you only allow identifiers if they span the whole line? That makes no sense. Also flex doesn't have a syntax for non-capturing groups - it has no concept of capturing groups in the first place. Beyond that, it would help if you explained what you changed from the OP's regex and why.

Comment: flex doesn't have `\b` either (nor would it make sense to rely on someone else's idea of what constitutes a word boundary instead of the lexical rules of your language).

Comment: @sepp2k: Sorry as I don't know flex, so restricting my answer only to what OP was looking for, i.e. support of single underscore, sandwiched within the whole word. I shouldn't have suggested things without knowing `flex` well enough. Thanks for pointing our the issues in my post. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you have to keep a few things in mind:

- Start with an alphanumeric value (`^`)
- End with an alphanumeric value (`$`)
- Optional underscore (`_?`)
- Possibly multiple underscores, always followed by alphanumeric `()*`

**Example**:

```
    ^[A-Za-z]+(_?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/RORy6P/5

You can leave the anchors away if you need.

Answer (score -1):

Walking through this, let's start with this:

```
^    [A-Z][A-Z\d_]+    $
```

Now, we want to say that we need to make sure that two consecutive underscores do not appear in the string.  Normally what we'd do is to include that in a negative lookahead, like this:

```
(?:(?!__).)+
```

When we plug that into our expression, we end up with something like this, which allows any character, so long as it's not a newline or a double underscore:

```
^    [A-Z]    (?:(?!__).)+    $
```

So, we can replace the dot with the character class we defined at the beginning:

```
^    [A-Z]    (?:(?!__)[A-Z\d_])+    $
```

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/USLkNw/1)

Edit: Just realized that you cannot have an underscore at the end either.  With lookaheads, you can chain them.

```
^[A-Z]    (?:    (?!__)    (?!_$)    [A-Z\d_]    )+$
```

Here, I added one negative lookahead for the double underscore and another for the underscore at the end.

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/USLkNw/2)

Comment: You're making the problem too difficult for yourself. For example negative lookahead is something that introduces a lot of complexity, which is not needed here.

Comment: Also flex does not support negative lookahead (or syntax for non-capturing groups - all groups are non-capturing in flex). And, as with most other answers, anchoring identifiers to the beginning and/or end of a line makes no sense.